# How get reporting interval in wql?

Tags: wavefront-telegraf

At the picture from Wavefront below I see that at between `11:13` and `11:14` there was one request to my API:

[image]

I need to display a requests per second graph. When I use `rate()` I get:

[image]

The request point in the Y axis has value `0.1` but I expect `1` request. And if I change scale, the Y value changes as well. From [documentation](https://docs.wavefront.com/ts_rate.html) :

> rate() finds the per-second rate of change between pairs of adjacent (successively reported) data values, where the later value is greater than the earlier value. The rate of change between a pair of increasing data values is computed as follows: 1. Subtract the earlier data value from the later value. 2. Divide the difference by the number of seconds in the reporting interval.

How can I get the reporting interval in the query to make it show the request count correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [align()](https://docs.wavefront.com/ts_align.html) + [ratediff()](https://docs.wavefront.com/ts_ratediff.html) do what I want

[image]